как вывести из метода значение а не ссылку python?
Подскажите, как в питоне вывести значение переданной переменной аргумента из одного класса другому? Получается, что передается ссылка, а нужно значение.
вот код:
class Test:
    def test(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self.name)

    def get_out(self):
        print(self.name)


class Test2:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self.name)


out = Test2("refdfdf")
out2 = Test()
out2.test(out)
out2.get_out()


out2.test(out) -> out2.test(out.name) и всё заработает, у вас test принимает name, а отдаёте вы класс туда, а не его поле name

понял благодарю т.е. получается как я понимаю конструктор класса Test2 создает поле self.name локальный атрибут и ему передается аргумент name и чтобы нам его передать классу Test надо его объвить и через экземпляр класса передать ему ссылку с полем name и он тогда залетает в класс Test и там его можно вывести из метода либо что-то там с ним сделать.. ?

Как вариант в Test2 можно тоже сделать метод get_out и дёргать его, чтобы получить поле. Можно получить поле "вручную", как я предложил, можно получить поле в самой функции test, вы сами решаете, какая у вас архитектура. То, что вы написали - примерно да, но я вашу формулировку понял не до конца.

видимо репутацию -2 получил неспроста а за тупость и глупость вопроса)) ну что делать надо как-то учиться))

Ну так то странно. Обычно минусуют вопросы вообще без кода и без желания в чём-то разобраться, мне лично не очень понятно, зачем тут минусуют, видно же по всему, что начинающий, и код в вопросе есть. А чёткость изложения требовать от начинающего - ну, тоже странно.

да еще раз извините если что не так, и как то непонятно спрашиваю. Прохожу курсы по питону ООП на Степике и периодически что-то непонятно как работают методы, как они передают аргументы друг другу. Сейчас дошел только до статик и класса метода, где можно вызывать что-то либо из экземпляра либо cls. из самого локального свойства класса и что-то ему передавать . Иногда туплю, простите..
